# How can i add Pause and Play funtion in one button in windows media player using c#?

Tags: c#

I am currently making windows media player and facing the problem with pause and play function in one button.
Here is my Code its not working except pausing the video. how can i resume the video again by same (pause) button ?

In Class :

```
public void play(AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer p1)
{
    p1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
public void pause(AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer p1)
{
    p1.Ctlcontrols.pause();      
}

myClass1 mc1 = new myClass1();
mc1.play(axWindowsMediaPlayer1);
mc1.pause(axWindowsMediaPlayer1);
```

Comment: your `play` method is actually pausing the controller with `p1.Ctlcontrols.pause();`

Comment: opz ! my mistake sorry...i just updated my code please check it once again..

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Media Players `playState`property and then Play or Pause it. 
To reuse the code you already have, you can add the following criteria:

```
myClass1 mc1 = new myClass1();
if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
{
     mc1.pause(axWindowsMediaPlayer1);
}
else
{
     mc1.pause(axWindowsMediaPlayer1);
}
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562461(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: @RohailAhmed please mark this answer as resolved for future searches, +1

Comment: @S.Dav as i am new here so don't know where is Mark option..guide ma please :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows media player has a useful property Ctlcontrols that gives you many options:

To pause:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
```

And another options:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = // a double value...
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
 .....
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: At the first line it has pause().

Comment: Then explain your code that you wrote. The code you wrote, at the moment, will simply stop it for a brief delay and then keep playing it.